# How does Access determine filepaths?

Tags: microsoft-access

In access when the serverpath is declared and a filepath is listed, if there are two separate symbolic paths how does access choose which path is valid and which is invalid?

I have a split accdb and my back end is hosted on a shared folder. Someone in the IT department created a bunch of shortcuts to the shared folder hosing my back end and there are now two different symbolic paths to the back end. Access does recognize symbolic paths as server paths, but how does it choose? The front end will link to the back end using one path but not the other, so how does access make that decision?